# web3.eth.getAccounts not working with infura

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, web3js

I'm using web3 beta-37 (Since every version has its own issues)
Anything under the line web3.eth.getAccounts in the deploy function isn't working.

When I run the code it just shows nothing!

Here is the code:

```
const HDWalletProvider = require('truffle-hdwallet-provider');
const Web3 = require('web3');
const {interface , bytecode} = require('./compile');

const provider = new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic,
'https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/my_project_id');

const web3 = new Web3(provider);

const deploy = async() => {
    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
    console.log('Attempting to deploy from account', accounts[0]);
    const result = await new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(interface))
                             .deploy({data: bytecode, arguments: ['Hi There!']})
                             .send({'from': accounts[0], 'gas': '1000000'});

    console.log('Contract deployed to: ', result.options.address);
};
deploy();
```

Also, testing this in mocha shows error while it works when using ganache-cli

```
const assert = require('assert');
const HDWalletProvider = require('truffle-hdwallet-provider');
const Web3 = require('web3');
const {bytecode , interface} = require('../compile');

const provider = new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic,
'https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/project_id');



let accounts;

beforeEach(async () => {
  //Get a list of all accounts
  accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

});

describe('Inbox', () => {
  it('address', () => {
    assert.ok(accounts);
  })
```

Here are the results with different versions:

beta-46: Cannot read property map() of undefined

One answer on stack exchange says use beta-36 to fix this issue

beta-36 and beta-37: Nothing after the getAccounts() statement gets executed, blank screen.

beta-26:  core.addProviders is not a function

Comment: The code seems fine to me. I shouldn't be saying this but you don't actually have `my_project_id` in the Infura link, right? Apart from that, it seems weird that it is not working? What version of `web3` do you use? Can you verify that the provider is set correctly (perhaps through debugging)?

Comment: @nikosfotiadis on console.log(provider) it shows me a big object with 10 address array as well (with one address). So i guess provider is set correctly and no am not using  my_project_id. Also web3 version is beta-37.

Comment: can you share your `compile.js` file? and does `Attempting to deploy from account` this line get console logged?

Comment: @IftifarTaz it's fine am sure ....I've run test in mocha... This thing was working perfectly with ganache... And No... nothing after `const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();` gets console logged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had the same issue.

Try to remove the "/v3" part from the infura url:

```
const provider = new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic,
'https://rinkeby.infura.io/my_project_id');
```